# Why in ifelse function with AND statements the wrong results

Tags: r, if-statement, lag

I have the following dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(number = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))
```

In this dataset i want to create a second column, which shows if in the certain row of the first column there is a case, when first and second lags are equal to 0 and the first lead equals to 1. If this is a case, so the number 1 is put in the second column where change from 0 to 1 occurred (if not the case so equals to 44. As a result, in this output all rows in the second column should equal to 44 except the 8th.

here is my code. and in the comments below I will put a photo of the required result.

```
df1$t<-ifelse(df1[,1]==1 & lag(df1[,1]==0,1,default = 44) & lag(df1[,1]==0,2,default = 44)
                              & lead(df1[,1]==1,1,default = 44)
                              ,1,44)
```

Comment: When you have, e.g., `lag(df1[,1]==0,1,default = 44)`, I think you want `lag(df1[,1],1,default = 44) == 0`. And I don't think you need `default = 44` in all the leads and lags, you've got that covered by the last argument of `ifelse()`. Instead, set the defaults to `1` for the lags and `0` for the `lead` since in your desired result the first row result is `0`, so it's "pretending" the non-existent lags for the first row are `1`.

Comment: Thank you , that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Athough the OP has asked for an explanation why his code does not return the expected result (which is addressed by  [Gregor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479292/why-in-ifelse-function-with-and-statements-the-wrong-results/56480705#comment99549394_56479292)) I would like to propose an alternative approach.

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to find all sub-sequences in `df1$number` which consist of two zeros followed by two ones, i.e., `c(0, 0, 1, 1)`. Then, the row which contains the first one in the sub-sequence should be marked by a `1` while all other rows should get `44` as default value.

As of version v1.12.0 (on CRAN 13 Jan 2019) of `data.table`, the `shift()` function recognizes negative lag/lead parameters. By this, a column can be shifted by multiple values in one batch. The row numbers which fulfill above condition are identified by a subsequent join operation. Finally `df1` is updated selectively using these row numbers:

```
# use enhanced sample dataset, rows 10 to 21 added
df1 <- data.frame(number = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1))

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, t := 44] # coerce to data.table, pre-populate result column
# shift and join
idx <- df1[, shift(number, 2:-1)][.(0, 0, 1, 1), on = paste0("V", 1:4), which = TRUE]
df1[idx, t := 1] # selective update
df1
```

> ```
>     number  t
>  1:      1 44
>  2:      1 44
>  3:      0 44
>  4:      0 44
>  5:      0 44
>  6:      0 44
>  7:      0 44
>  8:      1  1
>  9:      1 44
> 10:      0 44
> 11:      1 44
> 12:      0 44
> 13:      1 44
> 14:      1 44
> 15:      0 44
> 16:      0 44
> 17:      1 44
> 18:      0 44
> 19:      0 44
> 20:      1  1
> 21:      1 44
>     number  t
> ```

This works essentially as OP's approach by shifting and comparing with expected values. However, OP's approach requires to code four comparisions and three shift operations while here the shifting is done in one step and the comparison of all columns simultaneously is done by the join operation in the second step.

#### Additional explanations

The shift operation

```
df1[, shift(number, 2:-1)]
```

returns

> ```
>     V1 V2 V3 V4
>  1: NA NA  1  1
>  2: NA  1  1  0
>  3:  1  1  0  0
>  4:  1  0  0  0
>  5:  0  0  0  0
>  6:  0  0  0  0
>  7:  0  0  0  1
>  8:  0  0  1  1
>  9:  0  1  1  0
> 10:  1  1  0  1
> 11:  1  0  1  0
> 12:  0  1  0  1
> 13:  1  0  1  1
> 14:  0  1  1  0
> 15:  1  1  0  0
> 16:  1  0  0  1
> 17:  0  0  1  0
> 18:  0  1  0  0
> 19:  1  0  0  1
> 20:  0  0  1  1
> 21:  0  1  1 NA
>     V1 V2 V3 V4
> ```

In the subsequent join operation,

```
df1[, shift(number, 2:-1)][.(0, 0, 1, 1), on = paste0("V", 1:4), which = TRUE]
```

`which = TRUE` asks for returning only the indices of matching rows which are

> ```
> [1]  8 20
> ```